# Effects (DropShadowEffect) in Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, effects

I noticed the Effect Property is missing in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 so I did some googling and apperently it was dropped due to performance reasons. I basically want to do something like this

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <TextBlock.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </TextBlock.Effect>
</TextBlock>
```

*And*

```
<Image ...>
    <Image.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

So is there some other way to get a `DropShadowEffect` in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7? And are there any news if it'll be in the next release?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that one of two things would need to happen before this was put back in. (It was in the CTP.): 1) devices would need to be more powerful; or 2) a new faster algortihm for generating the effect would need to be created. I don't expect to see either of these any time soon but would be happy to be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the image you can just simply create a drop shadow in Photoshop/Gimp etc (works well for me) and save it as .png.

With TextBlock it is a bit harder. For instance, create a half-transparent image with the shadow and place both TextBlock and the Image inside the Canvas. Change the Canvas.ZIndex="integer" attached property to place them in a specific order - image has to be underneath. Also shadow should be blurred.

The drawbacks are:

- Shadow is static.
- Doesn't really suit metro UX.

Comment: Your first suggestion is exactly what I ended up doing. For both Image and Text actually :)

Comment: I reckon shadows can still work fine with metro design, like what they have done for the new Xbox live interface. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
<TextBlock ...>
 <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
  <TranslateTransform X="3" Y="3" />
 </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>

<TextBlock ...>
</TextBlock>
```

I wanted a shadow effect and this worked for me. You need to put same content in both textblocks (except textblock name). X and Y are the horizonatal and vertical distance of shadow from text. You can also use negative numbers if depending on position of shadows.